# Loop through all files and folders using FSO BUT ignore specified sub-folders/text string

Tags: excel, vba

Please allow me to start off by saying I am EXTREMELY new to programming and this is also my very first post on a website forum, ever! So forgive me if proper etiquette etc has not been followed.

The task I am trying to carry out is an Excel VBA problem.

I am trying to create a tool/macro that, for any given folder path, lists all files in all folders (and sub-folders) in an Excel spreadsheet BUT (and this is the crucial part) to ignore a list of specified exceptions.

I have picked up bits and pieces over the internet over the last few weeks and have managed to get to the point of listing everything (using FileSystemObject, this seems to be answered many times on the web already, thankfully).

I cannot, for the life of me however, find anything that allows for exceptions to be specified.

The reason I need to do it this way is because I am testing literally thousands of thousands of sub-folders and almost a million files so this takes a lot of time (and this process must be repeated on a monthly basis!). If however, I can specify which sub-folders to ignore (and there are many), either based on the whole sub-folder path or a string within the folder path, this (in theory) would save me loads of time.

In summary and as an example:

For Top Level Folder Path: `C:\This is the top folder\`

Which contains the following sub-folders (each of which contain further sub-folders and files):

```
Sub-folder 1
Sub-folder 2
Sub-folder 3
Sub-folder 4
Sub-folder 5
```

I want to return all files and folders but skip sub-folders 3 and 5 (or skip a specified sub-folder within a sub-folder). The sub-folders to be ignored will be based on specified filepaths within another tab ("exceptions") on the Excel worksheet.

I am very new to programming and have heard mention of potentially using the Dir object or Shell object but in my research so far the FileSystemObject (FSO) is the quickest/most flexible so would prefer for the solution to be based on use of FSO.

Current relevant code extract is as follows:

```
Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder, _
    IncludeSubFolders As Boolean)
    'Declare the variables
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim NextRow As Long

    'Find the next available row
    NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Cells(NextRow, "A").Value2 = objFile.Path
        Cells(NextRow, "B").Value2 = objFile.Name
        Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = objFile.DateLastModified
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
    Next objFile

    'Loop through files in the subfolders
    If IncludeSubFolders Then
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
            Call RecursiveFolder(objSubFolder, True)
        Next objSubFolder
    End If
End Sub
```

Hoping then for the outcome to be that every single file from all the sub-folders is listed EXCEPT from those sub-folders listed on the "exceptions" tab.

I have been stuck on this for ages so any help would be much appreciated!

P.S. Not as important but as a bonus would be great if the code can also return, next to the "Date Last Modified", the user who last saved each file (c.600 users on the drive).

P.P.S The version of Excel I am using is 2010.

Comment: How many exceptions do you have? If it's just a few, there are some simple tricks to use, that aren't useful if the list is long

Comment: Thanks Sam - Usually only a few, I'd say per run of the tool up to 10 sub-folder paths to be excluded. However there may be thousands of sub-folders of a similar nature to be excluded which is why I also need functionality to exclude based on a string within the sub-folder path so they can all be excluded in one go i.e. If all sub-folders 1-5 contain another sub-folder within each called "To be deleted", then I want to be able to say "ignore all folder paths containing the words "To be deleted". They can then be done in one sweep rather than thousands of individual whole folder paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of eliminating certain folders:

- Read the files and information into an array
- filter the array
- write the array to the worksheet

I used a dictionary to collect the information before writing it to an array.

Here is the code, along with a routine that calls the recursive routine and also writes to the worksheet.

Note that I have qualified the worksheet names. Otherwise it defaults to activesheet, over which you may not have control.

Also note that the process of working within VBA arrays is much speedier than the multiple worksheet write operations in your original code.

```
Option Explicit
Public dFI As Scripting.Dictionary

Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder, _
    IncludeSubFolders As Boolean)
    'Declare the variables
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    'Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim arrFI(1 To 3) As Variant

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            arrFI(1) = objFile.Path 'This is superfluous since it is also the key
            arrFI(2) = objFile.Name
            arrFI(3) = objFile.DateLastModified
            dFI.Add Key:=objFile.Path, Item:=arrFI
    Next objFile

    'Loop through files in the subfolders
    If IncludeSubFolders Then
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
            Call RecursiveFolder(objSubFolder, True)
        Next objSubFolder
    End If
End Sub

'----------------------------   
Sub GetList()
    Dim FO As Scripting.Folder
    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim V As Variant, W As Variant
    Dim vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long

    Dim WS As Worksheet:            Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Dim R As Range
        Set R = WS.Cells(1, 1)

        Dim wsEX As Worksheet:      Set wsEX = Worksheets("Exceptions")
        Dim vEX As Variant
        With wsEX
            'assumes exceptions are in column A
            vEX = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        End With

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set FO = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Ron\Documents\Data") 'or whatever
Set dFI = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Call RecursiveFolder(FO, True)

V = dFI.Keys

For Each W In vEX
    V = Filter(V, W, False, vbTextCompare)
Next W

'create results array
ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(V) + 1, 1 To 3)
I = 0
For Each W In V
    I = I + 1
    vRes(I, 1) = W
    vRes(I, 2) = dFI(W)(2)
    vRes(I, 3) = dFI(W)(3)
Next W


With R.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

*If you have a large list of excluded subfolders, it may or may not be more expeditious to filter on a worksheet using the `autofilter` or `advancedfilter`.  You would have to test to see whether that method works faster than the VBA Filter function*

Comment: Hi Ron, thank you very much for the above. Great explanation however the code is far beyond me at the moment so was trying to fully understand before responding! If I'm not mistaken you are saying that firstly everything is returned in an array THEN exceptions removed then pasted to the worksheet? Do you know if there is a way to skip the exceptions so that they are not included in the array in the first place? This is what I had in mind with a view to significantly speeding up the process. If everything must first be included in the array than I presume this will take longer overall?

Comment: @Haris **What happened when you tried it?**  It should run a lot faster (5-10x) because you are not doing all those worksheet writes. You will always have to read the file name -- either to save it or test to see if it is in your exception list.  Testing each name one at a time will likely take longer than filtering them out at the end.

Comment: @Haris If the above is not fast enough, in some testing (on network drives), I have found that using the Shell object to run the command window `Dir` command is faster than the FSO methods, but the differences seem insignificant on a single computer.

Comment: @Haris And finally, the `Filter` function does look for `contains`, so you can specify merely the parent subfolder, as you seem to indicate you want to do.

Comment: Hi Ron. Just ran it now on a folder with c.3000 files with 2 sub-folders excluded and it took 7m22s. Also ran it with the solution I currently have (doesn't have exclusions facility so these must be manually extracted and does have additional elements to the code i.e creates a further 10 columns and inserts formulas into each) and that took 3m40s. I couldn't possibly understand as to why it is quicker but they are the results.

Comment: @Haris Clearly there is something you are not sharing, or an issue with how you are implementing this routine on your system.  I just ran my routine on a folder with 3927 files in various subfolders, and it ran in 11.6 **seconds**.  With two subfolders excluded, dropping the file total to 3060, the procedure ran in the same time.

Comment: @Haris BTW, with only 3000 files taking minutes to process, my opinion is that your speed issues have little to do with the file reading/filtering routines.  Your routine takes seconds to run on my machine also.

Comment: Wow 11.6 seconds! In terms of the code I only shared what I thought was relevant at the time I posted (I can post the whole code if it will help as my ultimate aim in all of this is speed!). I ran your code exactly as you posted it. I wonder if the speed difference is to do with the fact I am on a workplace network and anywhere up to 600 people potentially using the system at once during working hours. That being said, the PCs we use are still reasonably quick (very similar to my PC at home) so don't understand why such a huge disparity. Thank you for all your help anyway.

Comment: @Haris As I wrote above, accessing a network drive, that has no where's near the use you described, I found much better speed using the `Shell` and the `CMD /c Dir` method to write to a text file, then process the file names that way.

Comment: @Haris For fun, I wrote a routine using the `Shell` which resulted in the same output as the FSO and your original routine.  The FSO and your original, with **30,000** files (on a local drive), took about 70 seconds to run.  The `Shell` routine produced the same output in about 3.2 seconds.  It is likely there are other issues slowing down your code, but the directory read/write routine can be sped up.

Comment: That's crazy. From what I have read on the web so far there are 3 ways to do it. FSO Object, Shell Object and Dir (I think). But I also hear they have their own strengths and weaknesses e.g. for my project I need to be able to return the filepath filename and date last modified which apparently works well with FSO? I have loads to learn but am embarrassingly excited about the start of my programming journey!

Comment: @Haris If you open the CMD window, you can examine the various arguments for the `Dir` command (**NOT** the VBA `Dir` function).  Those parameters can be returned, but then you have to do some programming to "put them together".  Not as convenient as the FSO, but faster.